# How to include un-included HDD space to fedora 14

Tags: fedora, fedora-14

I have fedora 14 installed.

I have 320 GB HDD, when I installed fedora, I included only 100 GB to root. Remaining 220 GB is now not usable.

My Question is how can I include the remaining 220 GB to my total usable disk space.

**UPDATE:** 
I just want to bring those 220 GBs in use, whether it takes making a separate partition or resizing already existing partition or anything....

Output of fdisk -l

```
[root@syed aqeel]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x97dd97dd

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   204802047   102400000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       204802048   221186047     8192000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Are the 220 GB unpartitioned? Do you want to add an additional partition or resize the one you have? Could you post the output of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: @Matteo Thanks a lot for you looked at it, I have added output of fdisk -l to my question, please have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all upgrade: Fedora 14 is no maintained (end of life on 2011-12-08)

If you are inexperienced beware that these are dangerous operations: an error could make you loose data (no guarantee on instructions and hits).

You have two options:

1. Create a new partition with the free space and mount it somewhere

   - add the partition with fdisk (**do not modify the existing ones**)
   - format it (example: `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda3`)
   - mount it (example: `mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/additionalpartition`)
2. Resize/move your partitions with GParted ([example](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted))

   - **Backup everything**
   - **Make sure your backup is OK**
   - read GParted documentation
   - boot with a live a CD with GParted
   - resize your partitions